# Unable to display multiplication table using slider in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Below is the code which I wrote in Xcode for displaying multiplication table when the slider is adjusted; the minimum value of the slider set was 0.05 and maximum value was 1. There is a tableview and slider in the project. I have added print statements to debug the code. When I add the Table1.Reload() in the end to the sliderChanged function, I am getting multiplication table of 2, but when I adjust the slider it is not changing. The slider value is getting struck. But, as soon as I remove the reload methodic the slider values are properly changing, but the multiplication table is struck at 0.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  //  var cellcontent[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
    var cellcontent = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 50 )
    var countr=50
    var count:Float=0.0
    var count2:Int=0
    var i=0
    var j=0
    internal func multiply(){
    print("check1")
        while j<50{
        // print(i)
            i+=1
          //  yourArray.insert("Hey, I'm first!", atIndex: 0)
            cellcontent[j] =  i*count2
           // cellcontent.insert(cellcontent[j],at:j)
    print(cellcontent[j])
            j=j+1
        }
    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellcontent.count
    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell=UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default,reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        //   cell.textLabel?.text="Top row"
     //   print("c")
        //multiply()
        cell.textLabel?.text=String(cellcontent[indexPath.row])
        return cell


    }
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

    @IBOutlet weak var Table1: UITableView!

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        //slider.maximumValue=Float(Int(countr))
        count=(slider.value*20)
        count2 = Int(round(count))
        print(count2)
        print(count)
    multiply()
    //     Table1.reloadData()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! I tried your code with `Table1.reloadData()` out-commented, and found, that your code has a very basic bug:
In function `multiply()`, you have a `while` loop that increments `j` until it is 50, and sets the contents of your data source to this value. As soon as `j` has reached 50, nothing changes any more.
So you had to correct your loop to show what is required.

Comment: If you can provide an alternative of how the solution might look like it will be great ! I am new to swift and xcode.

Comment: The simplest bug fix would be to insert `j = 0` just before your `while` statement in `multiply`.

Comment: It does work for me. Did you out-comment `Table1.reloadData()`in `sliderChanged`?

Comment: After you mentioned I out commented Table1.reloadData(), and I am getting values like this265505
265510
265515
265520
265525
265530
265535
265540. Count2 value got approximated to 5 and I was expecting 5 multiplication table to be displayed in the tableview

Comment: So your problem that nothing is updated when you move the slider is solved. I thus suggest that you accept the answer. I don't know if these are the numbers that you wanted to display. If not, this is a different problem and you should post another question.

Comment: I had to move var i=0 into multiply function and then the code worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad that I could help! Happy programming!